# Error for python bot-framework: Unauthorized Access. Request is not authorized

Tags: python, botframework

I am working with a python based bot using the bot-framework. I am using the sample cookiecutter echo template. [Echo Bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/python/02.echo-bot)

I have deployed the bot code as a AWS lambda function, connected via API gateway. Bot emulator testing with ***NO*** APP credentials are successful.

I am getting error when i am trying to test it with registered APP ID and APP Password. I have registered my bot using the following url: 
[dev bot framework](https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new)

Do i need to add any additional authentication provision in my bot? It will be great if someone can point me to the correct direction. Thanks!

This is the error trace back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abhishek.mishra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\botbuilder\core\bot_framework_adapter.py", line 209, in process_activity
    await self.authenticate_request(activity, auth_header)
  File "C:\Users\abhishek.mishra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\botbuilder\core\bot_framework_adapter.py", line 241, in authenticate_request
    self.settings.channel_service,
  File "C:\Users\abhishek.mishra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\botframework\connector\auth\jwt_token_validation.py", line 42, in authenticate_request
    raise Exception("Unauthorized Access. Request is not authorized")
Exception: Unauthorized Access. Request is not authorized
```

Comment: You say bot emulator testing is fine. Is that completely local? And when the authentication fails, are you adding the app ID/Password to your emulator test, or is that after you have deployed? You don't want/need to have the app ID/Password set up if you are doing completely local testing. It just needs to be added when you deploy.

Comment: So i am running 3 types of tests with the configuration and results below: **a.** Local Test - Bot-Flask application locally with no app id/Password - result: PASS **b.** Test with AWS Deployment - Bot-Flask application deployed on AWS with no app_id/password - result: PASS **c.** Test after registering the app on Bot Portal with app_id/password - result: **FAIL** **Unauthorized access.**

Comment: Have you added you appid and password  to config: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/python/02.echo-bot/config.py

Comment: Yes, I did update the config.py with app Id and password. After registering the App on not framework portal. That is when i got these errors.

Comment: Are all 3 test cases using the Emulator or are you using different chat clients? (Because there are multiple people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @KyleDelaney yes all the test cases are using the emulator. Eventually i want to launch this bot via the MS-Teams channel for my team.

Comment: @AbhishekMishra - Have you entered your app ID and password in the Emulator? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-emulator?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#connect-to-a-bot-running-on-localhost

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney, yes i have put in the app ID and password in the emulator. But that has not changed the result.

Comment: @KyleDelaney, in the documentation. I came across this on page [Bot Registraion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). It says that `Supports account types, you must choose one of the 2 multi-tenant types that is: Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD - Multitenant) or Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox, Outlook.com), when creating the app, otherwise the bot will not work.`

Comment: @AbhishekMishra - Had you been creating an AAD app registration manually? Did you try creating a new AAD app registration with the correct supported account types? Did that information solve your problem?

Comment: @KyleDelaney, yes i was creating the app registration manually. I was able to use the bot, without any error based on the information above. However, that is not compliant to the security requirements on my organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer this question myself as i was able to work around the error. It does bring up certain security issues but resolves the invalid access issue.

As per the documentation [Bot Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

> In the section Supports account types, you must choose one of the 2
>   multi-tenant types that is: Accounts in any organizational directory
>   (Any Azure AD - Multitenant) or Accounts in any organizational
>   directory (Any Azure AD - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts
>   (e.g. Skype, Xbox, Outlook.com), when creating the app, otherwise the
>   bot will not work.

Making this change to the App registration resolved the error and the service is working fine. Thanks to everyone that tried to chip in with their inputs.

Comment: This seems really weird and I can't find where to change the tenant.